How to solve uninterruptible sleep process deadlock without reboot
I have a process stuck in uninterruptible sleep.
The problematic syscall is a read syscall towards /dev/fd0, which is not backed by a real floppy drive.

I am trying to use modprobe and rmmod (both with the force option) to unload the floppy module but getting a resource busy error for both.
kill -9 does not work either, since the process is uninterruptible.

Is it possible somehow to "reset" the floppy block device to solve this deadlock?
I would like to avoid rebooting this VM unless absolutely necessary.
